# Best way to save objects across dynos in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, database, object, heroku, socket.io

I wrote a simple multiplayer game (from 2 to 8 players) with Node.JS using Express and Socket.io and it is hosted with Heroku. Each game's state is saved as an `Object` inside an `Array` which contains every active game. I just realized that if there are too many games at once, Heroku will split the users across several dynos (~servers) which will bring issues when scaling up.

Once several dynos will be needed, it is possible that some instances won't have access to the global `Array`. A good solution would be to use a database instead of memory. However, I have trouble figuring out which solution would be perfect for my case.

Each game is represented by an `Object` which is frequently manipulated by the server to reflect the current state of the game. Which solution would be perfect for my game without having to rewrite the whole code?

Comment: Maybe check out Firebase? Its a realtime document database

Comment: welcome to stack overflow. please add code snippet and technical details about the ask.

Comment: "it is possible that some instances won't have access to the global Array"—no, this is _guaranteed_, by design. Dynos are independent, interchangeable, and disposable. Each dyno will have its own, fully independent array. (And depending how many processes you're running on each dyno, and how you're doing that, it's likely that each dyno will have _more than one_ "global" array.)

Comment: @Chris Yes, indeed, it is guaranteed to happen if users of the same game are split across dynos. Is rewriting my code to handle a database my only choice?

Comment: Well storing state in global variables is a bad idea for _any_ application in _any_ hosting environment. Yes, you'll have to use some sort of shared state like a database, client-server memory store (if you don't need to persist the data anywhere), etc. Bergur suggests Firebase, which is probably worth looking into for your use case.